# How can I know the file size in bytes during downloading in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am using windows chrome. I want to know the file size in bytes during or before downloading the file in chrome. Chrome only shows the size in mb. How can I know it in byte?

Comment: Multiply by 1,048,576.

Comment: @Terry There will be an error as the size in mb has already be rounded to  1 decimal place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [chrono](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn/related?hl=en)
and when you click on the downloading file or downloaded file there you can see the size in bytes.

[image]

Comment: Just as an aside: note that this actually starts the download. Also, this only works if the web server (correctly) provides those details. Some downloads might not show any size at all (when in progress), and a plugin won't fix that.